# Cannot receive incoming audio/video call in conversation control

Tags: skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

In my application, I'm using the skype web sdk with the conversation control.

I can start and receive chats, but when I try to add audio/video modality, by pressing the corresponding button, the other user wont see the incoming call.

But when I stop the call the user is getting a "missing call" notification.

The other user's audio/video modality gets changed to "Notified", but even a manual accept wont start the call.

Thought, that the CC handles everything itself.

The Plugin is installed.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the JavaScript console when you press the buttons?

Comment: No, I dont see any errors. As far as I know there is no Debug +CC Api  key, so I had to use fiddler.